# Google Object Detection API - full description of the config files parameters and structure?

Tags: tensorflow

The following link provides brief description of the configuration file required for training https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md but it would be nice to get a full description on all of the parameters that can be specified as well as their meaning. Is there such a description available anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the docs mention, the configuration file represents ultimately a hierarchy of [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) objects, and the specification of these objects can be checked in [the source itself](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection/protos). Protocol buffers message definitions are quite readable even if you are not familiar with them, although you may need to check [the reference](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto2-spec) at some points.

[pipeline.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/protos/pipeline.proto) is the root object, and you can navigate through the files to see all the available fields for each element. Some parts are maybe better documented than others, but in general things are either explained or intuitively understandable. For example, [here is the specification for `FasterRcnn`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/protos/faster_rcnn.proto) (which is one of the possible [`DetectionModel`s](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/protos/model.proto)), and [here are the available `Optimizer`s](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/protos/optimizer.proto).